# How to get rows where at least two distinct values are in a column?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a log file and I want to report the `IP` addresses that initiated more than one (at least two) type of `protocol` connections, while showing these protocols. I'm trying to get these results by using **both** the DataFrames API and SparkSQL.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
+----------------+--------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-----+
|       Timestamp|Duration|Protocol|BytesOriginator|ResponderBytes|LocalHost|   RemoteHost| State|Flags|
+----------------+--------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-----+
|748162802.427995| 1.24383|    smtp|              ?|             ?|        1| 128.97.154.3|   REJ|    L|
|748162802.803033| 3.96513|    smtp|           1173|           328|        3|  128.8.142.5|    SF| null|
|748162804.817224| 1.02839|    nntp|             58|           129|        2|   140.98.2.1|    SF|    L|
|748162812.254572| 138.168|    nntp|         363238|          1200|        4| 128.49.4.103|    SF|    L|
|748162817.478016| 10.0858|    nntp|            230|           100|        4| 128.32.133.1|    SF|    N|
|748162833.453963| 2.16477|    smtp|           2524|           306|        5|192.48.232.17|    SF| null|
|748162836.735788| 13.1779|    smtp|          16479|           174|       16| 128.233.1.12|RSTRS3|    L|
|748162839.930331| 6.69767|    smtp|           3104|           371|        8|   139.91.1.1|    SF|    L|
|748162841.854151| 2.07407|    smtp|           1172|           380|        6|  128.8.142.5|    SF| null|
|748162854.814153| 131.659|    nntp|         319292|          1220|        4| 128.110.4.25|    SF|    L|
|748162866.207165| 51.8406|    nntp|         135714|           280|        4| 128.110.4.25|    SF| null|
|748162866.600750|0.402045|    smtp|              ?|             ?|        1| 128.97.154.3|   REJ|    L|
|748162869.790751| 172.363|    smtp|              0|             0|       16|132.230.6.100|    SF|    L|
|748162873.491682|  102.88|    nntp|            346|           180|        4| 128.32.136.1|    SF|   LN|
|748162875.237378| 5.32943|    nntp|             90|            85|        4| 128.32.133.1|    SF|    N|
+----------------+--------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------------+------+-----+
```

I tried to filter my dataframe but I keep getting an error, I don't know if I should use the Window function or not. By using SparkSQL, so far I'm getting the `IPs` but without the `protocols`.

Here's what I did:

```py
custom_schema = StructType([
    StructField('Timestamp', StringType(), True),
    StructField('Duration', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('Protocol', StringType(), True),
    StructField('BytesOriginator', StringType(), True),
    StructField('ResponderBytes', StringType(), True),
    StructField('LocalHost', StringType(), True),
    StructField('RemoteHost', StringType(), True),
    StructField('State', StringType(), True),
    StructField('Flags', StringType(), True) 
])

logs = spark.read.csv('lbl-conn-7.csv', header=False, sep=' ', schema=custom_schema)

# I get an error
logs.select('RemoteHost', 'Protocol').distinct().filter(F.countDistinct('Protocol') > 1).show()

logs.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.sql("select remotehost, protocol FROM mytable GROUP BY  HAVING COUNT(distinct protocol) > 1")
# It doesn't show the protocols
df.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by `RemoteHost` and collect list of distinct `Protocol` used. Then, filter the resulting dataframe using the size of protocols array:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

logs.groupBy("RemoteHost").agg(
    F.collect_set("Protocol").alias("Protocols")
).filter(
    F.size("Protocols") >= 2
).show()
```

Spark SQL equivalent query:

```sql
SELECT  RemoteHost, 
        collect_set(Protocol) AS Protocols
FROM    mytable 
GROUP BY  RemoteHost
HAVING  size(Protocols) >= 2 -- or count(distinct Protocol)  >= 2
```

If you want to keep all the columns, then use Window with `collect_set` function:

```
logs.withColumn(
    "Protocols",
    F.collect_set("Protocol").over((Window.partitionBy("RemoteHost")))
).filter(
    F.size("Protocols") >= 2
).drop("Protocols").show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works as intended. Is there any way I could flatten the result so I can get N rows rather than a nested array? I tried to use array_distinct(flatten()) but it tells me that you can't give an array of string.

Comment: @cdaveau yes, you can use `explode`, after filter add `.select("RemoteHost", F.explode("Protocols").alias("Protocol")).show()`. Or by using Window as shown above.